# Facebook FLogin button not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I used to have the FLogin button for enabling users to login using Facebook.
Lately , I updated my website to become HTML 5 compliant and made some other changes.

The FLogin is not working since then.
I also updated the FLogin code using the latest code provided by Facebook.
Still the login process is not working.

Can anyone share with me the exact code for FLogin for  HTML 5?

My websites are

Loud Letters - www.loudletters.com
Loud Review - www.loudreview.com

The FLogin related code is included in the end.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to append a script element for the FB JS-SDK to the element #fb-root, but that doesn’t exists yet, because it comes only later in your HTML code. (Btw., why did you mess with the code for asynchronously loading the SDK in that way, instead of using the code like it’s shown in the docs?)

You should make some use of your browsers error console when developing javascript.

Comment: Actually, I used the code provided by docs only but it seems lately they have put some alternate versions of FLogin implementation code.